# Is it ungrammatical to say "Have you any wool?"

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

See this [Baa Baa Black Sheep](https://www.google.com/search?q=baba%20sheep%20song%20lyrics&oq=baba%20sheep%20song%20lyrics&aqs=chrome..69i57j0l3.2344j0j7&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) song

> Baa, baa, black sheep, have you any wool?
>   Yes sir, yes sir, three bags full!
>   One for the master,
>   And one for the dame,
>   One for the little boy
>   Who lives down the lane
>   Baa, baa, black sheep,
>   Have you any wool?
>   Yes sir, yes sir,
>   Three bags full...
>   Baa, baa, black sheep, have you any wool?
>   Yes sir, yes sir, three bags full!

Why do they say "**Have you any wool?**"? why not "**Have you had any wool?**"?

Is it ungrammatical to say "**Have you any wool?**" in everyday conversation?

Comment: Also note that "have you **had**" is not a viable alternative as that is how the perfect tense is formed. You may have been thinking of "have you **got**" which is also addressed in the linked answers.

Comment: There is a famous comedy sketch based around "Have you any eggs?".